# Error in as.vector(data) when creating a mask for SECR

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying to create a mask in SECR using a .shp file. Always getting this error: *Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector* when i use the make.mask

this is my code:

```
fence <- rgdal :: readOGR('/Rdata/SECR', layer = 'building')
```

> OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile  Source: "/Rdata/SECR",
>   layer: "building" with 2492 features
>   It has 1 fields

```
library(secr)
#This is secr 3.2.1. For overview type ?secr

> qmask = make.mask(Quenda_traps,
+                   buffer = 300,
+                   type = "trapbuffer",
+                   poly = fence,
+                   poly.habitat = "FALSE")
```

> Error in as.vector(data) :    no method for coercing this S4 class to
>   a vector

```
    dput(Quenda_traps)
```

> structure(list(x = c(390576.21, 390637.85, 390594.93, 390528.49, 
>   390646.58, 390488.12, 390681.01, 390499.98, 390632.29, 390677.26, 
>   390642.7, 390710.33, 390690.37, 390741.81, 390588.01, 390655.06, 
>   390575.97, 390246.66, 390340.13, 390236.33, 390309.59, 390295.93, 
>   390164.11, 390065.71, 390120.42, 390117.17, 390091.7, 389875.57, 
>   390179.69, 390157.45, 390164.94, 390151.02, 390172.17, 390246.28, 
>   390263.25, 390256.32, 390308.2, 390135.06, 390093.3, 389914.13, 
>   389916.76, 389869.37, 389809.17, 389782.5, 389818.78, 389802.75, 
>   389818.78, 389771.52, 389792.74, 389791.25, 389905.36, 389832.62, 
>   389886.16, 389863.21, 389908.68, 389912.46, 389902.05, 389528.11, 
>   389661.6, 389689.54, 389657.88, 389678.71, 389569.25, 389618.44, 
>   389564.87, 389615.37, 389662.18, 389630.96, 389713.09, 389654.91, 
>   389744.37, 389762.02, 389715.87, 389696.2), y = c(6451727.44, 
>   6451613.91, 6451566.89, 6451511.85, 6451416.66, 6451402.77, 6451287.32, 
>   6451177.83, 6451164.84, 6451108.78, 6451188.57, 6450929.54, 6450855.04, 
>   6450723.66, 6450716.47, 6450451.11, 6450343.83, 6451821.46, 6451645.08, 
>   6451553.05, 6451588.21, 6451541.5, 6451509.03, 6451442.56, 6451358.89, 
>   6451222.49, 6451221.11, 6451303.03, 6451115.63, 6450989, 6450994.62, 
>   6450797.13, 6450761.88, 6450717.22, 6450719.62, 6450399.14, 6450403.03, 
>   6450352.38, 6450197.83, 6451841.15, 6451684.86, 6451526.92, 6451419.83, 
>   6451441.72, 6451316.83, 6451367.43, 6451316.83, 6451235.39, 6451105.9, 
>   6450981.72, 6450992.93, 6450910.1, 6450935.07, 6450787.37, 6450685.86, 
>   6450684.79, 6450600.42, 6451656.26, 6451534.65, 6451395.26, 6451267.42, 
>   6451262.1, 6451257.59, 6451248.14, 6451138.91, 6451096.22, 6451132.2, 
>   6450964.46, 6450964.24, 6450844.98, 6450864.8, 6450717.54, 6450620.58, 
>   6450519.48)), class = c("traps", "data.frame"), row.names = c("1001", 
>   "1002", "1003", "1004.1", "1004.2", "1005.1", "1005.2", "1006.1", 
>   "1006.2", "1006.3", "1006.4", "1007", "1008", "1009", "1010", 
>   "1011", "1012", "2001", "2002", "2003.1", "2003.2", "2003.3", 
>   "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007.1", "2007.2", "2008.1", "2008.2", 
>   "2009.1", "2009.2", "2010.1", "2010.2", "2011.1", "2011.2", "2012.1", 
>   "2012.2", "2013", "2014", "3001", "3002", "3003", "3004.1", "3004.2", 
>   "3005.1", "3005.2", "3005.3", "3006", "3007", "3008.1", "3008.2", 
>   "3009.1", "3009.2", "3010", "3011.1", "3011.2", "3012", "4001", 
>   "4002", "4003", "4004.1", "4004.2", "4005.1", "4005.2", "4006", 
>   "4007.1", "4007.2", "4008.1", "4008.2", "4009.1", "4009.2", "4010", 
>   "4011", "4012"), detector = "multi", usage = structure(c(1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 0, 1... ), .Dim = c(74L, 85L), .Dimnames = list(
>       c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004.1", "1004.2", "1005.1", "1005.2", 
>       "1006.1", "1006.2", "1006.3", "1006.4", "1007", "1008", "1009", 
>       "1010", "1011", "1012", "2001", "2002", "2003.1", "2003.2", 
>       "2003.3", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007.1", "2007.2", "2008.1", 
>       "2008.2", "2009.1", "2009.2", "2010.1", "2010.2", "2011.1", 
>       "2011.2", "2012.1", "2012.2", "2013", "2014", "3001", "3002", 
>       "3003", "3004.1", "3004.2", "3005.1", "3005.2", "3005.3", 
>       "3006", "3007", "3008.1", "3008.2", "3009.1", "3009.2", "3010", 
>       "3011.1", "3011.2", "3012", "4001", "4002", "4003", "4004.1", 
>       "4004.2", "4005.1", "4005.2", "4006", "4007.1", "4007.2", 
>       "4008.1", "4008.2", "4009.1", "4009.2", "4010", "4011", "4012"
>       ), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
>       "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
>       "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
>       "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
>       "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
>       "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
>       "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
>       "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
>       "82", "83", "84", "85"))), spacex = 0.240000000048894, spacey = 0.21999999973923, spacing = 79.5867492192872)

Comment: Hi @patL, the fence code works. I have all of the shp files in my directory. The error comes up when i try to use the make.mask function which is what i need to use for SECR

Comment: It'd be easier if you provide some sample of your data (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)). Also, you read your `shp` but you're using another object inside `secr::make.mask` function. How did you get this data... we must understand it in order to help you out

Comment: the 'building' from the fence code is the shp. file.> head(Quenda_traps)
              x       y
1001   390576.2 6451727
1002   390637.8 6451614
1003   390594.9 6451567
1004.1 390528.5 6451512
1004.2 390646.6 6451417
1005.1 390488.1 6451403. These are x and y coordinates of trap points within the area that the shp. file has. the shp. file is made up of buildings that surround the trap points

Comment: Hey Brooke. You must paste the output in your question, not as a comment. You must provide a sample of your `Quenda_traps` R object with a `dput(Quenda_traps)` and paste the output in your question.